# Denormalize a GCS file before uploading to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have written a Cloud Run API in .Net Core that reads files from a GCS location and then is supposed to denormalize (i.e. add more information for each row to include textual descriptions) and then write that to a BigQuery table. I have two options:

1. My cloud run API could create denormalized CSV files and write them to another GCS location. Then another cloud run API could pick up those denormalized CSV files and write them straight to BigQuery.
2. My cloud run API could read the original CSV file, denormalize them in memory (filestream) and then somehow write from the in memory filestream straight to the BigQuery table.

What is the best way to write to BigQuery in this scenario if performance (speed) and cost (monetary) is my goal. These files are roughly 10KB each before denormalizing. Each row is roughly 1000 characters. After denormalizing it is about three times as much. I do not need to keep denormalized files after they are successfully loaded in BigQuery. I am concerned about performance, as well as any specific BigQuery daily quotas around inserts/writes. I don't think there are any unless you are doing DML statements but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Most notably, you can only load data 1,000 times per day into BigQuery. If you have more than 1000 insert operations, you probably need to figure out how to batch them. (This can be done by pushing messages to PubSub, and using Cloud Scheduler to invoke a Cloud Run app to drain the PubSub topic, then _batch_ insert them to BigQuery.)

Comment: How many file per minutes do you have? Do you have realtime constraint? (What is the max duration between the file reception and the integration into BigQuery)

Comment: File count can very but say 100-500 files per minute. No realtime constraint perse but I would like data ingested in under 15 minutes from the time file appears in GCS.

Comment: If I use the UploadCSV method as shown here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local does that count as an insert operation and is limited by a daily quota? @AhmetB-Google

Comment: Which method are you exactly using? Is it load_table_from_file? I can't find UploadCSV in the document you have sent. Anyhow, it will probaly create a [load job](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJob) and [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) apply for them:                                                        
Load jobs per table per day — 1,000 (including failures)
Load jobs per project per day — 100,000 (including failures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Cloud Functions that are triggered when you upload a file to a bucket.

It is so common that Google has a [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-gcs-bq-streaming-functions-python) a tutorial just for this for JSON files [Streaming data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery using Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions).

Then, I would modify the example `main.py` file from:

```py
def streaming(data, context):
    '''This function is executed whenever a file is added to Cloud Storage'''
    bucket_name = data['bucket']
    file_name = data['name']
    db_ref = DB.document(u'streaming_files/%s' % file_name)
    if _was_already_ingested(db_ref):
        _handle_duplication(db_ref)
    else:
        try:
            _insert_into_bigquery(bucket_name, file_name)
            _handle_success(db_ref)
        except Exception:
            _handle_error(db_ref)
```

To this that accepts **CSV files**:

```py
import json
import csv
import logging
import os
import traceback
from datetime import datetime

from google.api_core import retry
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage
import pytz



PROJECT_ID = os.getenv('GCP_PROJECT')
BQ_DATASET = 'fromCloudFunction'
BQ_TABLE = 'mytable'

CS = storage.Client()
BQ = bigquery.Client()


def streaming(data, context):
    '''This function is executed whenever a file is added to Cloud Storage'''
    bucket_name = data['bucket']
    file_name = data['name']

    newRows = postProcessing(bucket_name, file_name)

    # It is recommended that you save 
    # what you process for debugging reasons.
    destination_bucket = 'post-processed' # gs://post-processed/
    destination_name = file_name
    # saveRowsToBucket(newRows,destination_bucket,destination_name)
    rowsInsertIntoBigquery(newRows)



class BigQueryError(Exception):
    '''Exception raised whenever a BigQuery error happened''' 

    def __init__(self, errors):
        super().__init__(self._format(errors))
        self.errors = errors

    def _format(self, errors):
        err = []
        for error in errors:
            err.extend(error['errors'])
        return json.dumps(err)

def postProcessing(bucket_name, file_name):
    blob = CS.get_bucket(bucket_name).blob(file_name)
    my_str = blob.download_as_string().decode('utf-8')
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(my_str.split('\n'))                                                                   
    newRows = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        modified_row = row # Add your logic
        newRows.append(modified_row)
    return newRows

def rowsInsertIntoBigquery(rows):
    table = BQ.dataset(BQ_DATASET).table(BQ_TABLE)
    errors = BQ.insert_rows_json(table,rows)
    if errors != []:
        raise BigQueryError(errors)
```

It would be still necesssary to define your map(row->newRow) and the function `saveRowsToBucket` if you needed it.